# Use object keys to generate HTML in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following object:

[image]

Now when I try to loop through it:

```
  {Object.keys(this.state.extras).forEach(key => (
                <div style={{'margin-top': '15px'}}>
                    <Addon data={this.state.extras[key]} addonTitle={key} type={key}
                           selectCallback={this.callbackSelectItem}
                           unSelectCallback={this.callbackUnSelectItem}/>
                </div>
            ))}
```

No html is displayed.

I have also tried:

```
let extra;    
Object.keys(this.state.extras).forEach(key => {
    extra += (<div style={{'margin-top': '15px'}}>
        <Addon data={this.state.extras[key]} addonTitle={key} type={key}
               selectCallback={this.callbackSelectItem}
               unSelectCallback={this.callbackUnSelectItem}/>
    </div>);
});
```

However this returns `"[object Object][object Object]"`

What have I done wrong?

### Update

The object key is `extras` when I set it on the `state`.

Comment: It seems to be `extra` and not `extras`? It also seems to be an array, not an object

Comment: First of all `extra` is not an object its an array. And extra[0] is an `obejct`

Comment: So the issue is resolved? Was it a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what's mentioned in comment above by @Chris related to proper usage of `extra` vs `extras` in your component which may or may not be bug, main issue of not rendering HTML is below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

`forEach` returns `undefined`, change it to use `.map` instead.

`undefined` would not render anything, while array of JSX would render as HTML (it will need `key` prop)

Furthermore `forEach` mutates underlying array so use it with caution.

Your code would probably need to be changed like below:

```
{Object.keys(this.state.extras).map(key => (
  <div style={{'margin-top': '15px'}} key={key}>
      <Addon data={this.state.extras[key]} addonTitle={key} type={key}
             selectCallback={this.callbackSelectItem}
             unSelectCallback={this.callbackUnSelectItem}/>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: This was actually the issue i will update my question